# $('').on('shown.bs.modal') event does not fire any function

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

My VisualForce page has the following code : and javascript tag to show the chart is as below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#idPanelGraphs').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    createChart('#barChart2', options);
});
});
</script>   

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade idPanel panel-group" id="vertical-tab">
<div id="idPanelGraphs" class="idPanel panel-group collapsible-group" data-chevron-down="glyphicon-chevron-down" data-chevron-up="glyphicon-chevron-up">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <div id="barChart2" style="height:255px;" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now as per code as soon as the idpanelGraphs is active the chart should have loaded. But it does not trigger the createChart function.

The same works when changing the modal to collapsable:

```
 $('#idPanelGraphs').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            createChart('#barChart2', options);
        });


<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade idPanel panel-group" id="vertical-tab4">
<div id="idPanelGraphs" class="idPanel panel-group collapsible-group" data-chevron-down="glyphicon-chevron-down" data-chevron-up="glyphicon-chevron-up">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseGraphTab">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            Graphs
            <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"/>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseGraphTab" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="barChart2" style="height:255px;" />
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: shown.bs.modal only works for elements with the class .model. You are using panels. So the event never gets triggered. Panels don't have a default callback, only custom.

Comment: any way to implement that?

Comment: Put your panel inside a modal..

Comment: @Keith you mean that just wrap the whole panel inside `<div class="modal" role="dialog">`, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works..

```
<div class="panel panel-default fade">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
</div>

<button id="test">Show panel</button>
```

```
function triggerPanel() {
    // All your code can go here..
    // createChart('#barChart2', options); ???

    $('.panel').toggleClass('fade');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').on('click', triggerPanel);
});
```